# Blazor server: read username outside of components

Tags: c#, blazor

I'm trying to get started with Blazor Server. Please bear with me - these are my first steps towards the web.

My little app only consists of a page with a few input fields that are saved in the database. To identify the user I added the following code to my .razor page: (in code-behind)

```
public partial class MyPage
    {
 [Inject] AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; } 
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                sessionController.UserKid = user.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                //userAuthenticated = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
            }
        }
…
```

Now I want to add a second page (and later more). But since I don't have a common "landing page", I have to re-insert the above code in every page!
So I want to authenticatethe user when the app starts before a page is displayed. Outside of a razor component. But now I don't know where to do it best. Does that belong in the "startup.cs"? And how does it work?

I just tried the following: I make my class "SessionController" available via:

```
startup.cs:
  public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    …
    services.AddScoped<SessionController>();
    }
```

The authorizations are to be determined and saved in the "SessionController" class: I call the user authentication in the constructor.

```
SessionController:
public class SessionController
    {
        private string _UserKid = "";
        public string UserKid 
        {
            get {
                return _UserKid;
            }
            set 
            {
    --> … Fetching User from Database via "value" as key …
        _UserKid = value;
            }
        }

        
        [Inject] AuthenticationStateProvider AuthenticationStateProvider { get; set; } 
        protected async Task Authorisation()
        {
            //Why ist it always null ?
            var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                this.UserKid = user.Identity.Name;
            }
            else
            {
                //userAuthenticated = "The user is NOT authenticated.";
            }
        }

        public SessionController()
        {
            Authorisation().Wait();
        }
}
```

My problem:

```
var authState = await AuthenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync ();
```

AuthenticationStateProvider is always NULL here.
I don't quite understand why. Can you help me?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0 : perhaps consider using the AuthorizeView component https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.authorization.authorizeview?view=aspnetcore-5.0. You typically don't need to use AuthenticationStateProvider directly.

Comment: Thanks for your advise! Can I use AuthorizeView outside of razor Components/Pages?

Comment: If you want to add authentication at particular routes  then add the @attribute [Authorize] tag (as described in the link above). If you want to validate the current user in your code behind, check the use of Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#procedural-logic - that looks like it wraps the use of AuthenticationStateProvider under the covers

Answer (score 2):

I'll answer my question myself because I was thinking far too complicated! The solution was very simple:

I don't have to do the authentication for each page individually, it is enough if I do it in "MainLayout.razor"! this component is used by all "Pages".

In order to make the user data available for other pages, I created a "Scoped" class:

```
public class SessionController
{
    public void InitUser(ClaimsPrincipal User)
    {
      ....doing some Authentication-stuff....
```

This is available to all pages if I add the following code to "startup.cs":

So it works for me.

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services)
         {
             ...
             services.AddScoped <SessionController> (); /

         }
```

In every Page I have to

```
[Inject] SessionController sessionController { get; set; }
```

so I can use it like this:

```
@if(sessionController.noSuchUser == true)
{
     <div class="row justify-content-center align-items-center alert alert-danger" role="alert">
         Sie haben keine Berechtigung für das Programm!
     </div>
}
else 
{
```

Comment: I did something rather similar but instead of using Service, I use cascading value that pass the value from MainLayout to all child pages. Something like   <CascadingValue Value="@username" Name="username" IsFixed="true">